# Return object comparing input with nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am having an object that looks like this:

```
const obj = {
   "cat1" : { 
                id: "1", 
                name: "Category1", 
                tiles: [{ tileName: "abc", searchable: true}, { tileName: "def", searchable: true}]
             },
   "cat2" : { 
                id: "2", 
                name: "Category2", 
                tiles: [{ tileName: "ab", searchable: true}, { tileName: "lmn", searchable: true}]
             },
   "cat3" : { 
                id: "3", 
                name: "Category3", 
                tiles: [{ tileName: "pqr", searchable: true}, { tileName: "", searchable: false}]
             }

}
```

Based on the search input , I need to check if the search item is included in each object basically inside two fields. One is `name` and the other is `tileName` inside `tile` array ( should be searched only if that object has `searchable` true ). It should be searched across `name` and `tiles` array

When search is "ab", the output should be

```
const obj = {
   "cat1" : { 
                id: "1", 
                name: "Category1", 
                tiles: [{ tileName: "abc", searchable: true}]
             },
   "cat2" : { 
                id: "2", 
                name: "Category2", 
                tiles: [{ tileName: "ab", searchable: true}]
             },
}
```

Code that I tried

```
function handleSearch(search)
{
  return Object.values(obj).map((item) => {
    if(item["name"].toLowerCase().includes(item.toLowerCase()))
      return item;
    })
   })
}
```

Comment: If the search term is "Category", should it return that category and all tiles within it, regardless of whether the tiles have a tileName that includes "Category"?

Comment: yes it should be searched across name and also the tiles array content

Comment: Is this data with which you're provided, or something you've created? An array of objects might be easier to work with.

Comment: Also, what if all the child tiles are `searchable: false` but the parent name matches... should that item parent be returned anyways, or not?

Comment: its basically an OR. search should be carried across name and also the tiles array content. For your question, yes it should be returned anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally create a generic `filterMap()` helper that combines the functionalities of both [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
// Combines filter() and map(). If no value is returned from the callback
// function (undefined) then the value is removed from the result. If a
// non-undefined value is returned, then that value is used as the map
// value. Returns a new array with the filtered/mapped values.
//
//     filterMap([1,2,3,4,5], (n) => { if (n % 2) return n * n })
//     //=> [1,9,25]
//
function filterMap(iterable, fn) {
  const filterMapped = [];
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const mapped = fn(item);
    if (mapped === undefined) continue; // skip current iteration
    filterMapped.push(mapped);
  }
  return filterMapped;
}
```

With the above helper defined you can get the desired functionality with relative ease

```
function search(searchString, object) {
  const searchIn = (whole, part) => whole.toLowerCase().includes(part.toLowerCase());

  return Object.fromEntries(
    filterMap(Object.entries(object), ([key, { tiles, ...category }]) => {
      // If the category name matches, return the whole category as is,
      // without filtering the tiles.
      if (searchIn(category.name, searchString)) {
        return [key, { ...category, tiles }];
      }

      // If the category name did not match, filter the tiles.
      const matchingTiles = tiles.filter((tile) => (
        tile.searchable && searchIn(tile.tileName, searchString)
      ));

      // If there are one or more matching tiles found, return the
      // category with only the matching tiles.
      if (matchingTiles.length) {
        return [key, { ...category, tiles: matchingTiles }];
      }

      // If neither the category name nor one of the tiles matched,
      // nothing (undefined) is returned, thus the entry is removed
      // from the result.
    })
  );
}
```

```js
function search(searchString, object) {
  const searchIn = (whole, part) => whole.toLowerCase().includes(part.toLowerCase());

  return Object.fromEntries(
    filterMap(Object.entries(object), ([key, { tiles, ...category }]) => {
      // If the category name matches, return the whole category as is,
      // without filtering the tiles.
      if (searchIn(category.name, searchString)) {
        return [key, { ...category, tiles }];
      }

      // If the category name did not match, filter the tiles.
      const matchingTiles = tiles.filter((tile) => (
        tile.searchable && searchIn(tile.tileName, searchString)
      ));

      // If there are one or more matching tiles found, return the
      // category with only the matching tiles.
      if (matchingTiles.length) {
        return [key, { ...category, tiles: matchingTiles }];
      }

      // If neither the category name nor one of the tiles matched,
      // nothing (undefined) is returned, thus the entry is removed
      // from the result.
    })
  );
}

const obj = {
  "cat1": {
    id: "1",
    name: "Category1",
    tiles: [
      { tileName: "abc", searchable: true },
      { tileName: "def", searchable: true },
    ],
  },
  "cat2": {
    id: "2",
    name: "Category2",
    tiles: [
      { tileName: "ab",  searchable: true },
      { tileName: "lmn", searchable: true },
    ],
  },
  "cat3": {
    id: "3",
    name: "Category3",
    tiles: [
      { tileName: "pqr", searchable: true  },
      { tileName: "",    searchable: false },
    ],
  },
};

console.log('search "ab"', search("ab", obj));
console.log('search "3"', search("3", obj));

// helper

// Combines filter() and map(). If no value is returned from the callback
// function (undefined) then the value is removed from the result. If a
// non-undefined value is returned, then that value is used as the map
// value. Returns a new array with the filtered/mapped values.
//
//     filterMap([1,2,3,4,5], (n) => { if (n % 2) return n * n })
//     //=> [1,9,25]
//
function filterMap(iterable, fn) {
  const filterMapped = [];
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const mapped = fn(item);
    if (mapped === undefined) continue; // skip current iteration
    filterMapped.push(mapped);
  }
  return filterMapped;
}
```

In the above code we use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert the object to an array. The array is then transformed using our newly defined `filterMap()` method. Finally the resulting array is transformed back into an object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

The code makes use of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), the [spread syntax in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals), and the [property definition shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions).

---

For those using TypeScript, `filterMap()` should be defined like:

```ts
function filterMap<A, B>(iterable: Iterable<A>, fn: (item: A) => undefined | B): B[] {
  const filterMapped: B[] = [];
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const mapped = fn(item);
    if (mapped === undefined) continue; // skip current iteration
    filterMapped.push(mapped);
  }
  return filterMapped;
}
```

The answer might still leave you with:

> Not all code paths return a value. (7030)

In which case you must either explicitly return from the callback function.

```ts
  // ...

  // If neither the category name nor one of the tiles matched,
  // nothing (undefined) is returned, thus the entry is removed
  // from the result.
  return; // <- explicit return at the end
})
```

Or alternatively set `"noImplicitReturns": false` in your TypeScript settings, to allow implicit returns.

Comment: I am getting a lot of type errors when used with typescript

Comment: @lrr97 I've updated the answer, you'll find the TypeScript definition/usage below the original answer.